# Is it possible for DatabaseCleaner to not reset a given table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-cleaner

Does Database Cleaner support a way to reset all tables except a given table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :except => %w[users])
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that. It's on the Github page.